# How to display blob image on TCPDF in Yii?

Tags: yii, blob, tcpdf

Is there a way to display a blob image in TCPDF in Yii? I've tried calling this function but it doesn't show any pictures.

```
    public function actionDisplayAgencyIcon()
{
        $info = BaseAgencyInfo::model()->find();
        $id = $info->agencyID;

        if($id == null || trim($id)=='') {
        echo "error in image, bad ID value [{$id}]";
        exit();
        }

        $model=BaseAgencyInfo::model()->find("agencyID = '{$id}'");

        if($model->agency_logo == null){
        echo "error in image, using ID [{$id}] ";
        exit();
        }

header('Content-Type: gif,jpeg,png');
echo $model->agency_logo;
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: Does anyone here have any idea how?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a proper header:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $model->agency_logo;
```